# OnClick - prevent user from multiple submits

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to prevent multiple form submit from client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926816/how-to-prevent-multiple-form-submit-from-client-side)

We have a project management tool which we are using, but when a user submits a log under task they click the submit button several times. this adds in several entries of the same information.

I have tracked down the code within the PHP file and I have seen online many solutions for on submit click. I have been playing around for the last four or five hours but unfortunately I have been unable to get anything to work. I was hoping someone could provide a little assistance:

This is the code that I have in the PHP file:

```
<input type="submit"  class="button" value="<?php echo $AppUI->_('update task'); ?>" onclick="updateTask();" />
```

effectively I just want the user to click the button, and after a single click. It is either greyed out or the user is unable to click any more.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just disable the button in `updateTask()` function:

```
document.getElementById("mysubmit").disabled = true;
```

This assummes you add ID to your submit button.

If it's an AJAX submit, make sure you reenable the button if the submit fails.

Comment: Thank you :), If I wanted to make a popup... for example please wait.. It that much more complicated???

Comment: No, it's quite easy.. Especially if you use [blockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block) (you don't even need to disable the button then, see this [demos](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page))

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply disable the button in your updateTask() script?

```
document.getElementByID("myButton").disabled='disabled'
```

If the updateTask function is too generic, then your button could call a more specific function that deals with just that button:

```
function myButtonClicked() {
    document.getElementByID("myButton").disabled='disabled';
    updateTask();
}
```

and then change your button to call myButtonClicked instead of updateTask.

```
<input type="submit" ... onclick="myButtonClicked();" />
```

Comment: Vanilla JS version (The question wasn't tagged with jQuery): `document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = 'disabled';`

Comment: Yup, sorry, was adding that while you were commenting, I guess!

Comment: yes, ok, but can I not edit it with in the code givien?

Comment: This is the code I have found that ask you to put somthing inif you have not written in the comment box `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function updateTask() {
 var f = document.editFrm;
 if (f.task_log_description.value.length < 1) {
        alert( '<?php echo $AppUI->_('tasksComment', UI_OUTPUT_JS); ?>' );
        f.task_log_description.focus();
        return;
    }
    <?php` Would I add the code here? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you would add the code in the updateTask function: "function updateTask() { document.getElementByID("myButton").disabled='disabled'; var f = ....". I would start with that. If you find that you need to re-enable the button later, it might get a little more complicated.

Comment: In answer to your other question above, yes, you could add the line "document.getElementByID("myButton").disabled='disabled';" before the "updateTask()" in the onClick property of the button, but I would say it's bad practice to put more JS logic in onClick beyond simply calling a function. It will make the code much harder to track down and debug and change things in the future. I would edit the JavaScript function itself (as you seem to be proposing in your subsequent comment).