# Multiple form submissions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Just to give some context I'm a self taught programmer with no formal education or experience so apologise for my code in advance...

Code below attempts to turn a site designed for an iphone into a single page site (i.e. using ajax). I'm having an issue with multiple form submissions... looks like this is occurring when clicking the submit button on form #id2.

I've done some research and was thinking of implementing the below jquery solution for preventing multiple form submissions:
[How to prevent form from submitting multiple times from client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926816/how-to-prevent-multiple-form-submit-from-client-side)

and this php solution for preventing multiple form submissionson the server side:
http://www.ideologics.co.uk/programming/how-to-prevent-multiple-form-submissions-in-php

Also some sites suggest that the ajax post code should set `async` to false and `cache` to false but I'm not entirely sure of the reason and whether this is applicable in my case.

The reason I had to use the delegate function is because clicking submit on form #id1 loads a form with id#2... I tried using the `on` function which jquery site says supersedes the delegate function but this didn't seem to work. I'm loading version 1.8.2 using google CDN.

```
var startUrl = 'menu.php';

$(document).ready(function(){
    loadPage(startUrl);
});

function loadPage(url) {
    $('body').append('<div id="progress">Loading...</div>');
    scrollTo(0,0);
    if (url == startUrl) {
        var element = ' #header ul';
    } else {
        var element = ' #content';
    }

    $('#container').load(url + element, function(){
        var title = $('h2').html() || 'Menu';
        $('h1').html(title); 
        $('h2').remove();
        $('.leftButton').remove();

        if (url != startUrl) {
            $('#header').append('<div class="leftButton">Menu</div>');
            $('#header .leftButton').click(function(e){
                $(e.target).addClass('clicked');
                loadPage(startUrl);
            });     
        } 

        $("#container").delegate("a", "click", function(e){
    var url = e.target.href;
            if (url.match(/example.com/)) { 
                    e.preventDefault();
                    loadPage(url);
                }
    });

    $("#container").delegate("form", "submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });

        $('#id1').submit(function(){
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('processform1.php',formData,processResults);     

    function processResults(data) {
        $('#id1').remove();
        $('#container').html(data);
    }

        });

        $("#container").delegate("#id2", "submit", function(event){
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('processform3.php',formData,processResults);     

    function processResults(data) {
        $('#id2').remove();
        $('#container').html(data);
    }

        event.preventDefault();
    });                 

        $('#progress').remove();        

});
}
```

Below is the index page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="myCustomIcon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="myCustomStartupGraphic.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="iphone.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="iphone.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Menu</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place this in your JS for the page the submit button is on

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", false);
    $("form").submit(function(){
      $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", true).val("Please wait...");
      return true;
    })
  })
</script>
```

You may need to use an `on()` event handler or do other tinkering depending on if the form is generated on page load.

Comment: I'm still getting the form submitted twice - but I like the button changing to please wait!

Comment: Is the form hard-coded on the page when it loads, or are you generating it dynamically through other Javascript?

Comment: The form is generated from a PHP script... it appears that the number of times the form is submitted gets progressively worse... I think I may need to unbind the submit events or move these out of the load page function.