# How to prevent submitting a form accidentally multiple times - on the client side without JS?

Tags: html, css, forms, client-side

When the user double clicks the submit button (or hits enter twice), **the form is submitted twice**.

**I want it to be sent only once**.

I **can't use JavaScript**, because of my client's request.

As a first approach, I want to find a solution **without modifications on the server-side**.

(I know it could be done easily [if JS was enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926816/how-to-prevent-form-from-submitting-multiple-times-from-client-side), or if I wanted to filter the incoming data by comparing it to the previously received ones on the server-side.)

Comment: CSS can't affect functionality...it styles what's there..no more.

Comment: Mis-click on the close. Retracted for clarity.

Comment: @Paulie_D sometimes it's perfect to affect the functionality by styling what's there, because "what's there" in the source code is not always the same as "what's there" on the user's screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. You must use js to disable the button (or otherwise prevent submission) after submission.

Remember also: No matter what you modify with js, the client can undo it with devtools. So sanitize everything server side.

Comment: I don't know about a solution either. But I still hope someone has an unexpected solution and shares it with us. By the way I've updated the question to clarify: I'm not looking for a hacker-proof solution, I just want to avoid accidental duplicates. I.e. a double click/enter should be filtered, but hackers can be ignored.

Comment: I've spent hours on finding a solution, unsuccessfully. I'll implement a filter on server-side, because I can't use JS. Otherwise I'd use this: `<form onsubmit="return (typeof submitted == 'undefined') ? (submitted = true) : !submitted">`. (If I could submit the form and check a checkbox at the same time using @mvuauja's label trick, it'd be easy without JS. Or if I could force the browser to show the requested page before it's rendered. Or if the CSS attribute selector worked real-time, to dynamically select an initially src-less iframe which is set as the target of the form...)

Answer (score 2):

Some very hacky, not semantic at all, workaround with CSS that will hide a link (style it as a button) on click, but I really wouldn't recommend that - javascript is way better (this will also not stop the user from hitting enter twice).

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="button-label">
<label for="button-label">
  <a class="button">click me</a>
</label>
```

Comment: Is it possibble to use a link for submitting a form, without using JS? I don't think so. Furthermore if I change the link to a submit button, then the checkbox won't get a synthetic click. Anyway, I like the approach, but I'd rather think about if hiding the whole form is possibble (to prevent enter as well).

Comment: you're right, probably not, didn't think about that. I'm afraid though you won't get anywhere without javascript then, and even that's not 100% reliable.

Comment: I'm afraid too, but I still hope someone has an unexpected solution and shares it with us. By the way I've updated the question to clarify: I'm not looking for a 100% relaible solution, I just want to avoid accidental duplicates. I.e. a double click/enter should be filtered, but hackers can be ignored.

Comment: if it doesn't have to be 100% reliable why not use javascript and ignore the users with javascript off?

Comment: I can't use JavaScript, because of my client's request. It's cheaper to make the product JS-less, than to provide support for customers to enable JS, or to lose them.