# How to prevent multi form substitution

Tags: jquery-steps

I have a form based on `jquery-steps` a PHP page to process the form submission.

The problem is that PHP file is too large and it need a lot of time to process ( API file are connected ) so some time my visitor click many time on the submit button.

My question is, how to disable the submit button after clicking on submit ?

Note :
My case is different of this case : [How to prevent form from submitting multiple times from client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926816/how-to-prevent-form-from-submitting-multiple-times-from-client-side)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent form from submitting multiple times from client side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926816/how-to-prevent-form-from-submitting-multiple-times-from-client-side)

Comment: Note : My case is different of this case : How to prevent form from submitting multiple times from client side?

Comment: Where is the difference?

Comment: I am using jQuery Steps: A jQuery wizard plugin
www.jquery-steps.com/
 which provide a submit button outside the form, in the method that you put you can see that they are only talking about the submit a form with submit button