# How to Prevent Duplicate Form Submissions

Tags: php, forms

I have simple email script with few forms and I am getting duplicate submissions...

So, what is the easiest way to prevent duplicate submissions?

My code..

```
<form action="main_contact.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
                  <input type="text" name="contact_name" placeholder="Name">
                  <input type="email" name="contact_email" placeholder="Email">
                  <input type="text" name="contact_subject" placeholder="Subject">
                  <textarea cols="30" name="contact_message" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                   <input type="submit" value="Send">  
                </form>

<?php
                  if(isset($_POST['contact_form'])){ 
                    var_dump($_POST);
                  }
                ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs to try and piece together the user journey?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand?

Comment: What I meant was why is this behaviour happening?  Is the user waiting for something to happen, and hitting the button multiple times?  Or do the logs or analytics reveal another reason?  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926816/how-to-prevent-form-from-submitting-multiple-times-from-client-side

Comment: Ahh yes.. users push the button twice or even more..

Comment: Just disable the button on submission?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to disable submit button after the form has been submitted:

```
$('form[name="contact_form"]').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: This is a straight forward approach to it. Furthermore, make sure that you are displaying a success message to the user following a submission. Even redirecting to a success page is effective, and can help track conversion. :)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to disable or make visibility hidden after just click on submit button. fist give a `id` to the submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="sub_id">
```

and then make it hidden or disable in javascript once you submit the form

```
document.getElementById('sub_id').style.visibility='hidden';
```

Answer (score -1):

If you used any framework like Laravel5 or Symfony you would get it "out of the box".

In short:
Register a session token and invalidate it after first form submission.

Comment: Hey.. Its simple email script so there is no MySql..

Comment: You don't need MySql to start a session and register a token.