# Prevent form from submitting multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have some code where I'm trying to prevent a form from being submitted multiple times. I found this code on another Stack thread but it doesn't work. Instead it submits the form infinite times and lags the entire server!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        console.log("hi")
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $(this).submit(function(){
                return false;
            });
            return true; //Tried with an without
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a picture of the output in the console:

[image]

This keep submitting the form. I just took a picture at that number.

The thread that I found the code above from is the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926816/how-to-prevent-form-from-submitting-multiple-times-from-client-side) and it has many upvotes.

Note that I have multiple forms per page, and many pages with many forms! A solution to one specific form is not sufficient. I need a global solution. Also I'm using Codeigniter.

Comment: Well it will cause a infinite loop, (1), because your checking the event form's submit, (2), and inside your submitting the form, go back to (1).  Try getting rid of the `submit()` callback, and attach the code to a simple button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the initial form submission so that you only do it after you've validated it.  But frankly, HTML5 won't submit if a form is not valid, so your code seems redundant.

Here is a working example that takes most of the JQuery out of the mix. It only submits the form one time.

You can also test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/5oyp6aa0/6/

```
$(function() {
    var theForm = document.querySelector("form");
    theForm.addEventListener("submit",function(evt) {
        // First, cancel the form's submission:
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        console.log("Navitve Submit Cancelled")
        if (theForm.checkValidity()) {
            // Then, only if it's valid, submit
            console.log("Manual Submit Triggered");
            theForm.submit();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: `evt.preventDefault is not a function.` evt is in the wrong function haha. i will test it again.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. Not awake yet!

Comment: It still submits multiple times. Submits over a thousand times in just 5 seconds.

Comment: @Nic Try the updated answer. Instead of redefining the submit event handling function again, this just submits if the form is valid.

Comment: It still does it unfortunately :S

Comment: With the updated answer I don't receive any input in the console. I don't think the event listener is firing for me.

Comment: @Nic If you open your console and run the fiddle, you will see the console entries.

Comment: I see that. I mean on my site it doesn't work. Nothing fires.

Comment: @Nic Then, you must have other code that has errors in it which is preventing this code from being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the event and using e.preventDefault()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("hi")
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $(this).submit(function(){
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It still submits multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but, shouldn't you just `return;` if it's valid, else stop submission like in the jQuery documentation's [example](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        console.log("hi")
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            return;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After none of these answers worked I decided to give it another shot. This works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        var attr = $(this).attr('submitted');
        if (typeof attr === typeof undefined || attr === false) {
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $(this).attr('submitted', 'submitted');
                $(this).submit();
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can get rid if both else branches. You dont need downvoting just everything. You may mark your answer as accepted if thats the fact.